# Self contained VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to create VirtualBox VMs which are entirely contained in a single
directory (including various aspects that are normally kept in a configuration in the ~/ directory).

The idea is to remotely mount the directory and run the VM on that machine, or carry a VM on a stick or SD card.

I'm particularly bother because I notice that VirtualBox tends to spread these things around.

Comment: Maybe something can be made the same way VMWare player opens one file = one VM with all the settings.

Comment: VM on SD card | VM over network == SLOW, also VBOX kept things in a single folder and ~/.VirtualBox what you mean by spread things around

Comment: @warl0ck Older versions of VBox kept config files in one folder and vdi files in another. Newer versions already do keep everything in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just put the virtual disk on removable/remote media and create a new VM pointing at the existing disk when I want to run it. Apart from from adjusting memory (and maybe video memory) the default settings for an OS work fine.

Alternatively, recent versions of VirtualBox can export and import VMs. I haven't used this, but I think it would copy the virtual disk around so may not satisfy your requirements.